# pthread_mutex_lock returns 22 in C

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm learning how to use Pthread in C. I've tried to use `pthread_mutex_lock`. It is supposed to return 0 when the locking is successful. But my program always returns 22 - invalid argument.

The code is as follow:

> `pthread_mutex_lock` is used in `work_function`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 2

void *work_function(void *param);

int count=0;
pthread_mutex_t mut;

int main(int args, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t tid[N];
    long int iterations = atoi(argv[1]);

    pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, work_function, (void *) iterations);
    pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, work_function, (void *) iterations);

    pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);

    if (count != iterations * 2)
        printf("Error: %d\n",count);
    else
        printf("Value as expected: count = %d\n", count);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *work_function(void *param)
{
    long int max_iter = (long int) param;
    int i, tmp;

    pid_t pid = getpid();
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();

    i = pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    for(i = 0; i < max_iter; i++) {
        tmp = count;
        tmp ++;
        printf("in thread: pid=%d and id=%u count=%d new\n", (unsigned int) pid, (unsigned int) id, count);
        // sleep(1);
        count = tmp;
        printf("haha\n");
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);

    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}
```

The following result is produced when `3` is passed in as the command line argument.

```
22
22
in thread: pid=36767 and id=6819840 count=0 new
in thread: pid=36767 and id=7356416 count=0 new
haha
haha
in thread: pid=36767 and id=6819840 count=1 new
in thread: pid=36767 and id=7356416 count=1 new
haha
haha
in thread: pid=36767 and id=6819840 count=2 new
in thread: pid=36767 and id=7356416 count=2 new
haha
haha
Error: 3
```

Comment: pthead_mutex_init(&mut, NULL); ?  or try using a different variable name than 'i' for it (so you don't have dual usage of the same local variable, as it is reused for the for(;;) loop counter, checking for compiler issue with this one)

Comment: @DarrylMiles, thanks very much, Darryl. Putting `pthead_mutex_init(&mut, NULL);` under `main` method solved my problem. I had a look at the other question, but couldn't find out how to initialise `pthread_mutex_t`. This works perfectly now.

Answer (score 5):

Initializing `pthread_mutex_t mut` solved my problem, by placing the following code under `main` method.

```
pthread_mutex_init(&mut, NULL);
```

Comment: As your mutex is of static storage duration, you can use the provided static initialiser instead: `pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`