# What are pthread lock return code values?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, pthreads

I'm trying to use pthreads in my executable and it's crashing on the mutex::lock() call. In the debugger I see that the crash is happening in std_mutex.h, where the call to __gthread_mutex_lock() is returning an integer of value 22.

It's a proprietary program so I can't share it nor can I reproduce the problem on a smaller program yet. What does this return value suggest I may be doing wrong?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html

Comment: "It's a proprietary program so I can't share it nor can I reproduce the problem on a smaller program yet." And how you expect someone to help you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pthread\_mutex\_lock returns 22 in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511046/pthread-mutex-lock-returns-22-in-c)

Comment: this might help: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html

Comment: Use std::thread in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the pthread link - it does not show the integer values though, only symbolic names. I expect someone to help me as the answer below shows. Last, I'm using STL already, no pthread directly hence the reference to std_mutex.h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possibilities to check:

1. Lock is already held by this thread.
2. Lock was never properly initialized.
3. Lock was already destroyed.
4. Lock was unlocked by a thread that didn't hold it.
5. Lock's memory was overwritten or corrupted.
6. Lock was previously locked by a thread that already held it.
7. Lock was copied.
8. Lock was dynamically allocated but statically initialized.

This assumes there's no vital information that you're leaving out. For example, I am assuming you would tell us if this was a recursive mutex, a process-shared mutex, or had any other special properties.

Comment: Thanks for the list! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I tried a simple lock() immediately followed by unlock() and it still crashes. That eliminates (1), (4). The lock is dynamically allocated but is not used statically,  eliminating (8). It's a class member variable pointer initialized in the constructor, eliminating (7).

(2) is possible but documentation shows no initialization required?
(5) is always possible but eliminating the critical section eliminates the crash, so unlikely
(6) what's wrong with relocking? as long as it was previously unlocked

libstdc++ is statically linked, may be related. We had to build with a workaround.